# Check for duplicate database entry

Tags: php, mysql

I've been making a form recently. It works fine. I just want to add one tweak to it that it shows an error if one registers an email id that has already been registered in the database.
Here's my whole php code::

```
<?php
      //include the connection file

      require_once("validation.php");

if( isset($_POST['send']) && (!validateName($_POST['name']) || !validateEmail($_POST['email']) || !validatePasswords($_POST['pass1'], $_POST['pass2']) || !validateContact($_POST['contact']) || !validateAge($_POST['age'])) ):?>
            <div id="error">    
                <ul>
                    <? if(!validateName($_POST['name'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Invalid Name:</strong> We want names with more than 3 letters.</li>
                    <? endif?>
                    <? if(!validateEmail($_POST['email'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Invalid E-mail:</strong> Type a valid e-mail please.</li>
                    <? endif?>
                    <? if(!validatePasswords($_POST['pass1'], $_POST['pass2'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Passwords are invalid:</strong> Passwords doesnt match or are invalid!</li>
                    <? endif?>
                    <? if(!validateContact($_POST['contact'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Please enter a valid number.</strong></li>
                    <? endif?>
                    <? if(!validateAge($_POST['age'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Please enter a valid age</strong></li>
                    <? endif?>
                    <? if(!validateWork($_POST['work'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Please enter work</strong></li>
                    <? endif?>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        <?php elseif(isset($_POST['send'])):?>
            <div id="error" class="valid">
                <ul>
                <?php
                require_once('connection.php'); 
                $query = "INSERT INTO employee (name, password, email, contact, age, gender, location, skill, work) VALUES ";                           
                $query .= "('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['pass1']."', '".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['contact']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['gender']."','".$_POST['location']."','".$_POST['skill']."','".$_POST['work']."')";
                // run the query
                mysql_query($query);?>
                <li><strong>Congratulations!</strong> You have been successfully registered!</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <?php endif?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, make your **email** a unique one:

```
CREATE TABLE employee { ..., UNIQUE KEY theemail (email) }   # in create table
```

or via query:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD UNIQUE KEY theemail (email);   # via console etc. phpmyadmin
```

then, you can just check the mysql_affected_rows as @sachleen said above:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO employee (name, password, email, contact, age, gender, location, skill, work) VALUES ";                           
$query .= "('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['pass1']."', '".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['contact']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['gender']."','".$_POST['location']."','".$_POST['skill']."','".$_POST['work']."')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$affected_rows = ($result ? mysql_affected_rows($result) : 0);
if ($affected_rows==0) {
   // fail
}
```

ot more simply:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
   // fail
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your comment `// normally =0` If the insert is successful (what I assume to be normal), it will be 1.

Comment: If there is a unique key, you won't have a chance to pass the mysql_query statement

Comment: yes, you've right in this, thanx, the mysql_query() return FALSE in this case. For that case i updated my tested solution to take this into account.

Comment: please edit your post (add a blank..) so I can remove the -1, which is currently locked.

Comment: @vlzvl: I just did what you advised me. It worked. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @vlzvl One more thing I want to add error message like "Email already exist" how can do this

Answer (score 2):

You can give the email field a `UNIQUE` constraint so there can be no duplicates. In that case, the `INSERT` query will fail and your query will return `false`.

```
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
    // Error, email already exists, no data was inserted
} else {
    // Successfully inserted row, print success message.
}
```

The `INSERT` query will actually **fail**, and not just return 0 rows modified.

Comment: Can you elaborate it? I'm a newbie in PHP. 
I've made the email field UNIQUE in SQL. What now? I mean I want to print the error alongside it as well. Please help!

Comment: @Sebas I've corrected my answer. Thanks for bringing that up in the comments below...

Answer (score 0):

DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD UNIQUE KEY idx_email (email);
```

QUERY: doesn't change, use your query.

PHP LAYER:

```
$query = "...";
try {
    mysql_query($query);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {
        throw new Exception('The email you used exists already');
    } else {
        throw $ex;
    }
}
```

The 1062 error is raised whenever a unique key is broken. We need to catch it because of the unique email field, but it could also be raised because you broke the primary key or another unique field that we ignore the existence. You will have to adapt this code in case you think some other unique constraints might break as well during this query.

Comment: Note that `mysql_query()` does not throw exceptions if the query fails. Use `if (mysql_errno() != 0)` instead.

Comment: in my case, by default, it does... umm

Comment: If you're using the old mysql extension, the only way it throws exceptions, AFAIK, is if you're trying to fetch the result of a failed query, and have an [error handler set to throw exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)!

Comment: f** just checked my code, I got confused indeed, I am raising the exception myself. Please apologize I'm going to correct this.

Comment: thanks for your understanding you're great! I commented according to my memory while at work, which as usual fooled me...

Answer (score 0):

All the answers suggest adding an index to the table, but since email is a text input, depending on your database the index might become really huge. I would add an index on like 5 symbols the most from the start and query for a particular email (thus moving the check for unique to the php side) instead of adding an index on whole column.

Comment: I would not worry about this problem of huge index just yet. And can you assign unique index for only first 5 symbols in mysql? if you can, then in case of emails this would be useless. Just think of these emails: jenny123@mail.com and jenny1985@mail.com.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not use `$_POST['name']` directly in the query. This is open for a [sql injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). So wrap it in [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). *Unless this is "play-with-code" that is not going to be used anywhere.*

To do your unique email validation, do apply `Unique` constraint to the email field, as been said already. But before inserting new line, do a query like this: `'select email from employee where email = '. mysql_escape_string($_POST['email'])`. Then check if anything was returned by this query. If number of rows returned more than zero, then this email is taken already. Otherwise we can insert the new row, as per insert query you already have.

Another thing, do separate your form code, validation and DB code. Like add function Validate_form() that will check all the form entries. If there are errors, return a string with all the problems described. If there are no errors, return null. 
This validate_form might include code for checking the existing email and do provide the error text in case email is alredy taken.

So if validate_form() does not detect any errors, then do run insert query.

Comment: Thanks, i already did as you instructed. Separated my actual page code, DB code and Validation code into 3 separate files and also included validation. It's working fine. 
One thing but, I really dont know much about "SQL Injection Attacks"; though I encounter the term quite often. Can you provide me a link where I can read about it or maybe improve my code??

Comment: @PrateekSachan the wiki link is in my answer. I believe there are a lot of information available online. For example related to php http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php